# Why in compilation-mode do my go (golang) compile errors not include the column on goto-error?

Tags: compilation-mode, golang

When I compile a simple (incorrect) go program like this from emacs

```
package main

func main() int {
}
```

I get this result

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/Go/" -*-
Compilation started at Mon Aug 12 22:37:46

go run assert.go
# command-line-arguments
./assert.go:3:6: func main must have no arguments and no return values
./assert.go:4:1: missing return at end of function

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Mon Aug 12 22:37:46
```

The problem is easier to see in a screenshot

[image: compilation results]

Notice how only the part of the filename and line number up to the second `:` is red.  This means that when I use `goto-error` emacs jumps to the start of the line, whereas the compile info has the column in it too.

This looks like a pretty standard compiler output so I would have thought emacs should be doing this by itself.

Is this a bug?  Or is it something I should be configuring?

I'm using emacs 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2 from ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation mode [documentation says the following](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation-Mode.html):

> To parse messages from the compiler, Compilation mode uses the
>   variable `compilation-error-regexp-alist` which lists various error
>   message formats and tells Emacs how to extract the locus from each. A
>   similar variable, `grep-regexp-alist`, tells Emacs how to parse output
>   from a grep command (see Grep Searching).

Basically `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist` defines a list of named regexps and `compilation-error-regexp-alist` says which of those compilation mode should try to use to match errors in your compilation buffer.

It seems that for whatever reason your emacs is configured in such a way that it isn't picking a regexp that properly matches filename:line_num:col_num. The default 'gnu regexp should match that. You try temporarily changing the value of `compilation-error-regexp-alist` to be just `(gnu)` and see if that fixes it for you:

```
M-; (setq  compilation-error-regexp-alist '(gnu))
```

Assuming that that works you probably then want to look at what the other regexp values are in `compilation-error-regexp-alist` and reorder them so that 'gnu matches before which ever other one you are currently matching against.

Comment: Setting `(setq  compilation-error-regexp-alist '(gnu))` did work thank you :-)  I guess I have a mode installed which has messed with the list.  Will investigate further.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I found the problem eventually... it was in my `.emacs` :blush: Some time in the last 10 years I had obviously put in a crazy regexp for some reason.  I removed it and all is good!